# wxPython: how to refresh UI when switching languages?

Tags: python, localization, wxpython, refresh, infinite-loop

I have a little program which I'm developing for practice. In the UI (built with wxPython) I have a drop-down presenting various language options.

**How I handle localisation:** I format individual strings by pulling from a dictionary `loc.lan["section"]`, where "section" is the key for a given string. `loc` is an object from a class I use to handle localisation.
I populate this dictionary by reading a json, which contains a dictionary of the above sections for each language available. On program start the program reads from this file, which also stores the last selected language, and populates `loc.lan` with the sections from the appropriate language.
This also happens when the user operates on the drop-down, and in this case the new selection is also recorded in the json file.

**The problem:** right now, if a user selects a different language, the strings that have already been formatted obviously don't refresh, so I have to restart the app for the change to take effect.

**The question:** what would be the most elegant way to make the language change instantly be reflected by the UI?
A friend has suggested to use a `continue` statement into the main loop, but I can't do that since the main loop is handled by the wxPython app's `MainLoop()` method.
What would be the best way to handle this? Should I restructure the whole system and do it differently somehow? Is there a way to operate on wxPython's main loop?

Comment: How many times do you think the average user is going to swap languages, whilst using your software? It would be a nice to have but in reality even main stream software just informs you that the changes will be made on reload.

Comment: That is sensible, but as I'm developing the program mainly for practice, I was wondering if it was at all possible to have it update in real time. It seems like a useful thing to learn.  
Incidentally, I recently found out about this: https://docs.wxpython.org/internationalization.html  do you happen to know if this provides the functionality I need?

Comment: No it doesn't. The issue is that much of the text to be replaced is already already being displayed on the screen and you have almost certainly created it in your initialisation. To replace it all, you would have to destroy any existing Gui and reinitialise it all. Which is why most say to hell with it and bang a message onto the screen, informing the user that they need to reload the program to see the changes. I know I do.

Comment: I see. Well, that makes sense I guess. Thank you very much.